# Bootstrap glyphicons only shown on hover in Chrome 33

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I have button group in my asp.net mvc application:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="btn-create-file-window" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-open-file" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-delete-file" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
</div>
```

After page reloading I get this result:

[image]

If I hover my mouse on the `btn-create-file-window` in Chrome33, I get expected result (same, as ie10). What am I doing wrong?

- Bootstrap v3.1.1 from Nuget
- Internet Explorer 10
- Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m
- my bad English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved in Google Chrome 34